# To find a number $d$ such that there are at least two points very close to each other.

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

> Suppose we have $226$ points in a $4$ by $4$ square. We have to find a number $d$ such that there are at least two points very close to each other, no more than a distance $d$.

---

I have thought of using the pigeonhole principle. Note that $226 = 15^2 + 1$. So we divide the $4*4$ square into squares of length $\frac{4}{15}$. Hence by pigeonhole, we must have one square with two points. Hence the reqd dist is $\frac{4 \sqrt2}{15}.$

Is the solution correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks

Comment: An easier approach is to say $d=\sqrt 2$ works without doing anything else. You can get a better $d$ if you take the number from packomania, which says the largest radius circle you can fit $225$ of in a unit square is $0.034611022344155608668101554325$.  You need to round up a bit because you allow the circles to go outside the square.